# Archivos en python: como hacer una columna que muestre la cantidad de vehiulos que transitaron para cada hora de ese dia por cadapasos por peaje

Tags: python

en un archivo scv, donde hay numeroa con puntos. Leer una fecha por teclado y hacer una tabla para consignar la cantidad total de vehiculos(moto, auto, auto con trailer, pesados2, pesados 3, pesados 4) que transitaron para cada hora de ese dia (de 0 a 23) en cada uno de los peajes(ILL,ILP,AVE,DEL,PB1,PB4,PB2,RET,SAL y mas) para un sentido de circulacion(centro o provincia)

Comment: Bienvenida a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y q realizar el [tour]. Para poder ayudarte, debes añadir un [mre], mostrando lo que has intentado o investigado, explicando con detalles el problema, el comportamiento actual y el comportamiento esperado. Puedes hacer clic en [edit] para agregar lo que falte a tu pregunta, de lo contrario podría terminar cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Hola Laura, bienvenida, para obtener una buena respuesta, es imprescindible formular una buena pregunta, esto implica, explicar claramente el problema, y adjuntar los códigos involucrados y los mensajes de error (si los hubiera) ambos en formato texto, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y la adaptes a los requerimientos del sitio, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)para evitar votos negativos y/o que sea eliminada, aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y obtener una medalla!.